# RoR: removing sensitive field from response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Is there any way to remove sensitive fields from the result set produced by the default ActiveRecord 'all', 'where', 'find', etc?

In a small project that I'm using to learn ruby I've a reference to User in every object, but for security reasons I don't want to expose the user's id. When I'm using a simple HTML response it is easy to remove the user_id simply by not using it. But for some task I'd like to return a json using something like:

```
def index
  @my_objects = MyObject.all

  respond_to do |format|
    ...
    format.json { render json: @my_objects, ...}
    ...
  end
end
```

How do I prevent user_id to be listed? Is there any way to create a helper that removes sensitive fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html) to restrict the attributes serialized in the JSON response.

```
format.json { render json: @my_objects.as_json(only: [:id, :name]), ...}
```

If you want to make it the default, then simply override the method in the model itself

```
class MyObject
  def serializable_hash(options = nil)
    super((options || {}).merge(only: [:id, :name]))
  end
end
```

Despite this approach is quick and effective, it rapidly becomes unmaintainable as soon as your app will become large enough to have several models and possibly different serialization for the same type of object.

That's why the best approach is to delegate the serialization to a serializer object. It's quite easy, but it will require some extra work to create the class.

The serializer is simply an object that returns an instance of a model, and returns a JSON-ready hash. There are several available libraries, or you can build your own.

Comment: That was fast! I think I'll go with as_json( except: [:user_id]) for now but I'll think about this serializer object. Thank you.